# Firefox and jQuery.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I run Firefox 105.0.1 and use jquery-3.6.1-min und want to post data to a Python Flask app listening on port 5555.

I can do that with chrome, edge and opera, but firefox gives me an error.

Here is my code:

```
var settings = {
  "url": "http://10.10.0.55:5555/test",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 2000,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": authdata
   },
  "data": JSON.stringify({
    "data": "mydata",
   }),
};

$.ajax(settings)
 .done(function() {
   alert( "success" );
 })
 .fail(function() {
   alert( "error" );
 })
 .always(function() {
   alert( "complete" );
 });
```

Is there a way to overcome this error in firefox?

Comment: What is `this error`?

Comment: Well there is an error code 0. In the meantime I found out this is a CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with this code. You could enhance it with http status codes, then you would get an error code 0. Which in turn mostly is a CORS issue, that can only be solved on server side.